# Php or jQuery, To Draw Shapes on Image by Users?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a web app which enable user to draw shapes (Arrow, Box and Line) on presented Maps in Image format on the webpage and this must be a Mouse event trigger. Can you please let me know which solution, rendering the best result,  is better to start?

Thanks

Comment: "Php or jQuery ?" I would say both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at

**[sketch.js](http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/)**